# For loop to append results from many clustering analyses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm running many clustering analyses and want to find out the optimal number of clusters (k) based on metrics. For each metric I want to create a table that appends the results from each run i.e. the number of clusters (k) used.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

ks = range(2, 10)
inertias = []
silhouette_avg = []

#kmeans param: use default kmeans arguments + full/EM algo
kmeans_kwargs = {
    "init": "k-means++",
    "n_init": 10,
    "max_iter": 300,
    "random_state": 10,
    "algorithm": "full"
}

def find_nclusters(ks, df):
    #scaler = StandardScaler()
    normalizer = Normalizer()
    for k in ks:
        # Create a KMeans instance with k clusters: model
        model = KMeans(n_clusters= k, **kmeans_kwargs)
        pipeline = make_pipeline(normalizer, model)
        # Fit model to samples
        pipeline.fit(df)
        # Append the inertia to the list of inertias
        inertias.append({'k_cluster': k,
                         'inertia_score': pipeline[1].inertia_})
        silhouette_avg.append({'k_cluster': k,
                           'average_score': silhouette_score(df, pipeline[1].labels_)})
    return inertias, silhouette_avg, pipeline

#Use my function as follows
inertias, silhouette_avg, pipeline = find_nclusters(ks, clean_df)
```

My function worked fine at the first loop at k = 2. However it stopped there and I was expecting results from k = 3 to k=10 runs appended to each table `inertias` and `silhouette_avg`. Appreciate any suggestions on how I can make it work!

Comment: @DYZ added the actual call as you suggested.

Comment: `inertias` is already a global variable, there is no point in returning and reassigning it. When you say " it stopped there," what exactly do you mean? Was there an error? If you add `print(k)` to the loop, does it print all `k`s?

Comment: To second what DYZ is saying I would avoid using global variables initialize your lists at the beginning of your `find_nclusters` method.

Comment: @DYZ @kpie there wasn't an error - `print(k)` only returned `2` and did not print all `k`s. thanks for tips I'll remove `inertias` and `silhouette_avg` as global variables

Comment: You may want to check if `return` is correctly indented in your actual code. If it is a part of the loop then the function returns after the first iteration. That would be the only rational explanation.

Comment: @DYZ thanks! yes indeed the actual code didn't have the correct indent as what is shown in the example above. Loop works fine and `print(k)` is returning all `k`s now.